# Heroku Moduke Not Found Error

Tags: python, heroku

[![][1]][1]

the module 'pyicloud' is listed in requirements.txt
I have checked using the 'ls' command- I checked the directory in which the package should be - and the package does exist on the heroku server.

The app gives no such issues on my local machine, even though there is no difference in the code
I also tried the suggestions given here : https://help.heroku.com/BWJ7QYTF/why-am-i-seeing-importerror-no-module-named-site-when-deploying-a-python-app
but it didnt work.

(venv)dhcp-10-4-0-197:mes-amis mananhora$ heroku run python manage.py db upgrade -a mesamis

```
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.16.18-62346b1 to 6.99.0-ec9edad
Running python manage.py db upgrade on ⬢ mesamis... up, run.1121 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from project import app, db
  File "/app/project/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from project.import_data.functions import import_data_blueprint
  File "/app/project/import_data/functions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyicloud'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku- Module Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065717/heroku-module-not-found)

Comment: You asked [the same question on April 27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065717/heroku-module-not-found). Please [don't repost questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/248627). There, I asked you how you "checked" that a Python module was available using `ls`. That doesn't make much sense. You didn't bother to answer. If you ask questions that don't make sense and don't bother to clarify them we can't help you.